# Can a Python RQ job reschedule itself and keep depending jobs around?

Tags: python, python-rq

I have a Python RQ job that downloads a resource from a webserver.

1. In case of a non-responding webserver, can the download-job reschedule itself and retry the download after a certain interval?
2. Several transformation-jobs depend on the download-job via

   `job_queue.enqueue(transformation_task, depends_on=download_job)`

   If the download-job could reschedule itself, are the dependent jobs kept along, and would finally execute, once the download-job finishes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I asked the question on the [python-rq](/questions/tagged/python-rq) GitHub project and the functionality is now included in version 1.5.0 of RQ.

1. RQ lets you now easily retry failed jobs. To configure retries, use RQ’s Retry object that accepts `max` and `interval` arguments.
2. Dependent jobs are kept in the deferred job registry until the job they depend upon succeeds and are executed only then.

For example:

```
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue, Retry
from somewhere import randomly_failing_task, dependent_task

job_queue = Queue(connection=Redis())
randomly_failing_job = job_queue.enqueue(randomly_failing_task, retry=Retry(max=3))
dependent_job = job_queue.enqueue(dependent_task, depends_on=randomly_failing_job)
```

And the sample tasks:

```
from random import choice

def randomly_failing_task():
    print('I am a task, I will fail 50% of the times :/')
    success = choice([True, False])
    if success:
        print('I succeed :)')
    else:
        print('I failed :(')
        raise Exception('randomly_failing_task failed!')


def dependent_task():
    print('I depend upon the randomly_failing_task.')
    print('I am only executed, once the randomly_failing_task succeeded.’)
```